# Webpack issue with image path generated

Tags: webpack

I am getting a weird issue while using webpack. Sometimes when I run the application using "`npm run start`" generating the image path as "`/./img/logo.png`", displays the image fine. but after some 3-4 refreshes the image goes away, though the path remains the same "`/./img/logo.png`". The console says 404 NOT FOUND.
I am using simple webpack config with bootstrap 4.

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a GH repo?

Comment: Actually no.. Bcoz I can see that when I work on my local machine.. If webpack config file can help I can share that